# Size in bytes for a vector of vector

Tags: c++, vector

I tried to find the size in bytes for a vector of vector. I need this size in order to allocate a pointer with malloc. It seems to me that I allocated too much memory, because when I try to copy the content with memcpy it says "access violation reading location ...". The strange thing is that it crashes only some times, even If i don't change the code. Is there something that I'm missing?

In order to fully understand my question here is a piece of code:

```
struct Node
{
    int total;
    float threshold;
    float value[2];
    int child [2]; 
};

vector<vector<Node>> NodeArray;
NodeArray.resize(100);

for (int  i = 0; i < NodeArray.size(); i++)
{
    NodeArray[i].resize(20);
}

int ArraySize = sizeof(NodeArray);
for (vector<vector<Node>>::iterator it = NodeArray.begin(); it != NodeArray.end(); ++it) 
{
    ArraySize += it->size() * sizeof(Node) + sizeof(it);
}


vector<vector<Node>> *NodeArray_d;
NodeArray_d= (vector<vector<Node>>*)malloc(ArraySize);
memcpy (NodeArray_d, &NodeArray, ArraySize);
```

Comment: You can't copy non-trivial types with `memcpy`. If you want to copy a vector, just do `vector<vector<Node>> copy = NodeArray;`

Comment: Can you explain *why* you need `malloc` in a C++ program?

Comment: Never `malloc` in C++ use `new` or even better use smart pointers. `malloc` just allocates bytes doesn't evoke a constructor.

Comment: I have to copy the content of the vector with memcpy in order to use it on the GPU. Actually in my case the memcpy and malloc will be CudaMalloc and CudaMemcpy, but the functionality is somehow similar.

Comment: Seems a bit harsh to downvote someone because they want to do something perfectly reasonable if slightly unusual. Perhaps now it's been made clear why they need it the downvotes can be retracted?

Comment: There seems to be a confusion about copying the vector or copying its data, but it is unclear to me what you actually try to achieve.  But anyway, calculating the size of the data and then copying starting from the pointer to the vector is impossible because vectors only contain pointers to the data.

Comment: @stefaanv: If I change the value of the first resize, let's say NodeArray.resize(4) everything is perfect. I don't think the problem has anything to do with the copy, perhaps the total amount of memory needed is not right.

Comment: NodeArray is a vector of vectors.  vectors don't contain data, they contain a pointer to their data, so a memcpy of &NodeArray, will never copy the data.  If that is not needed, then I don't understand why you are calculating the size of the data of the inner vectors (it->size()).

Comment: @Ana You'll need to allocate a block of `Node`s of the proper size, then loop through `NodeArray` and append the contents of its subvectors to the block. Or use a `Node[100][20]`.

Comment: @stefaanv: You're right, my mistake. I will try to copy it right.

Comment: Do you need to know the size of the `std::vector` object or the size of the dynamically allocated memory for all the objects?